# Use boost to recursively copy files of each lowest level folder in a given directory to another directory - C++

Tags: c++, boost, file-io, recursion, filesystems

I have a folder with many sub folders that also contains many sub folders that I'm trying to copy mixed files to one directory elsewhere.

It looks something like this
GrandParent/Parents/Children/files.*

I heard boost was the way to go to handle recursive folder operations. However, I'm not very familiar with boost. How should I approach this?

edit: please give an example using boost! Thanks SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple google search lead me to this - http://warpedvisions.org/2008/04/howto-directory-recursion-in-boost-and-other-tips/

Give it a try.

Comment: An answer on SO typically consists of more beyond a link itself.  Please capture the content here so that it might be useful beyond the life of that website.

Comment: Aah, my bad, thanks for pointing out, will do that from next time.

Comment: #include "boost/filesystem.hpp"
#include <iostream>

for ( boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator end, dir("./"); 
       dir != end; ++dir ) {
       cout << *dir << std::endl;                                    
}

//From the link above... exactly waht I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

google search [boost filesystem](http://www.google.com/search?q=boost%20filesystem) first hit

- [boost filesystem home](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm)
- [boost filesystem tutorial directory iteration](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/filesystem/doc/tutorial.html#Directory-iteration)
- [boost filesystem reference copy_directory and copy_file](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#copy_directory)

boost filesystem changed to version 3 recently. take care not to follow V2 tutorials.

Comment: An answer on SO typically consists of more beyond a link itself.  Please capture the content here so that it might be useful beyond the life of that website.

Comment: @Brian the answer is correct and detailed and answers the question of the OP. it is more likely to find up to date boost documentation on the boost site.

Comment: Sorry, it's not.  You're [risking deletion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) - "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are …barely more than a link to an external site"